# How to reuse php templates as shortcodes?

Tags: shortcode

I want to have a structure like:

```
wp-content  
    |themes  
        |myTheme  
            |page.php  
            |contact.php  
            |break.php
```

In a page from WordPress admin, I want to add:

```
[break]
[contact]
```

And it will print the contents of break.php and contact.php. I've been looking at the codex for add_shortcode, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to define the php that is used as the contents of the shortcode.

Comment: While this is doable, this isn't how you should theme your pages. Use custom page templates instead. You'll also find the template hierarchy diagram incredibly useful

Comment: And if there is a possible error in the code, there is a question how you will track that. Also if you plan to distribute the theme there is a security impact. Maybe this is why [WordPress Rest API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) has been invented.

Comment: Custom page templates are something I have used in the past, however, there's pages that are essentially the same, but using a block that differs here and there. Doing custom templates would essentially be creating a new page layout because I want to use a simple block on this page but a different block on another.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrap function for short code like that.

```
function simplest_shortcode_ever() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
        Your PHP Logic here
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'simple_shortcode', 'simplest_shortcode_ever' );
```

And then use it`[simple_shortcode]`